# MongoDB find data from array by field name

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have a mongoDB record like the below mentioned-

```
{  
    "d": { 
        "education": [ 
            { 
                "school": { "name": "one", "id": "1" } 
            }, 
            { 
                "school": { "name" : "two", "id" : "2" } 
            } 
        ] 
    } 
}
```

now I am running a mongo query to fetch all the school name I have in my record, which is like this-

```
db.test.find({},{"d.education.0.school.name":"1"})
```

but the result is not what I am looking for, it is giving empty-

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("5722385b964f6cb39d49f875"), 
    "d" : { "education" : [ {  }, {  } ] } 
}
```

I am hoping to get result something like this-

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("5087c96338aeb0538a832574"), 
    "d": { 
        "education": [ 
            { 
                "school": { "name" : "one" } 
            } 
        ] 
    } 
}
```

The name of the school from first record of the school array. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
db.test.aggregate([{"$project":
{"d.education.school.name":true}},
{$unwind:"$d.education.school"},
{"$limit":1}])
```